# Bringing Qmail offline

Tags: email, email-server

I am currently using a linux server to archive all qmail emails (sftping them from main server to a server whose soul purpose is an archive).  The problem with this is that

1) The space required is increasing significantly every month
2) It is very slow to access

In my local environment I have a networked Synology Diskstation that we currently use to store files from Windows 10 PCs.

Ideally I want to use the same diskstation to transfer over the entire email archive and access it locally.  Anyone have a clue what software I can use and whether it is straight forward to set up (or whether I need to read a 100 page manual to figure it out!).  Alternatively, I don't mind sticking it on a cloud based service but would need to be able to read the qmail messages.

Many Thanks for any help you can provide in my quest of making my life more efficient!